# Use ON NULL with create table from pivot result (in oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, null, pivot

Can ON NULL (or DEFAULT?) be used in conjunction with select * from () pivot () to replace nulls with zero when creating a table?

Explanation:
A transaction table contains customer_id, item_qty, department, transaction_key, sales

The task is to create a table which provides a single row for each customer containing the number of items, transactions and sales in each department.

```
create table merchandise_summary as
select * 
from (select customer_id, item_cd, department, transaction_key, sales from transaction_table)
pivot (
    sum(item_qty) items,
    count(distinct transaction_key) transactions,
    sum(sales) sales
 for department in ('socks', 'dresses', 'shoes')
)
```

This table will create null values for any customer not purchasing anything from the socks department, but in reality the value should be zero (the customer purchased zero socks).

A separate query could update the values from null to zero after the table is created, but is it possible to set a default for the columns? Assume there are many departments and a number of fields to aggregate, listing each column individually is not convenient. (And, isn't the pivot operator supposed to make these operations more elegant?)

Comment: pretty sure it would need to be nvl() outside the inline subquery (the select * statement) but this requires listing all the columns as in select nvl(socks_sales, 0) as socks_sales, nvl(socks_items, 0) as socks_items... et cetera -- but im going to try it to confirm

Comment: maybe there's a solution using pl sql to pull a list of column names and run an 'alter table .. ' after it is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you'd better use short aliases:

```
create table merchandise_summary as
select customer_id, item_cd, department, sock_s, sock_tr, dress_s, dress_tr, shoe_s, nvl(shoe_tr, 0) shoe_tr
from (select customer_id, item_cd, department, transaction_key, sales from transaction_table)
pivot (
    sum(item_qty) s,
    count(distinct transaction_key) tr,
    sum(sales) sales
 for department in ('socks' as sock, 'dresses' as dress, 'shoes' as shoe)
)
```

> The database generates a name for each new column. If you do not
>   provide an alias for an aggregation function, then the database uses
>   each pivot column value as the name for each new column to which that
>   aggregated value is transposed. If you provide an alias for an
>   aggregation function, then the database generates a name for each new
>   column to which that aggregated value is transposed by concatenating
>   the pivot column name, the underscore character (_), and the
>   aggregation function alias. If a generated column name exceeds the
>   maximum length of a column name, then an ORA-00918 error is returned.
>   To avoid this issue, specify a shorter alias for the pivot column
>   heading, the aggregation function, or both.

"Assume there are many departments and a number of fields to aggregate, listing each column individually is not convenient."

I suppose you need to list all the columns anyway if you're using CTAS. Oracle doesn't give convenient names to pivot columns.

Comment: listing all the columns could be arduous, intended on using the create table as select * from pivot () as in the example above.

Comment: @justin cress But in this case you can't apply NVL (it won't work inside PIVOT)

Comment: I agree. NVL does not solve the problem. So, investigating the DEFAULT or ON NULL options.  IDK, maybe there's not an elegant solution.

Comment: @justin cress DEFAULT won't help. It works only if you omit the column value. Oracle 12c has DEFAULT ON NULL clause, but you still need to list all the column names: create table t1 (n default on null 0) as select 1 from dual;